# Prefilled new item with dynamic value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, person-or-group, new-item

I need to click on new item and the employee field to be prefilled with correct employee
[image: Prefilled new item]

I added this functionality using a code in modern part editor but when I click on cancel button a new empty item is saved. Any suggestion how to do this, beside creating a customized power app form, because there are a lot of employees and I need to create a new form in power apps for each of them. I also tried with rest api, but the problem I face is for this column because it is a person column. Any suggestion for this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The only supported way to do this in the modern experience is to use Power Apps to customize the New form. Attempting to manipulate the New form or the Details Pane using JavaScript injection and DOM manipulation is not supported and, even if you were to get it working, it is very likely that it will stop working at some point in the future due to changes Microsoft will have made to the DOM.

For more information on customizing list forms using Power Apps, please see: [Customize a SharePoint list or library form by using Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)